# Vb.net access database control

Tags: vb.net

! expected layout
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhkPP.jpg)

Hi guys, is there a VB.net froms application access database code that enables me to add new column to an already created table in VB.net.

I am building a temperature registration app so I want it to be able to add new column and possibly name it as to the "current day date"

Comment: Adding columns frequently (daily) would be poor database design.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql